# Can't read a config section from configuration file

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I am reading a config file to get the value of the `baseAddress` that is located as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>...

<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="nameX" behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfigurationX">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://xxx"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

...</configuration>
```

I was able to find the `services` config section but there was no service section under it.
Here is the quick watch:[image]

How to get the **http://xxx** from this config file??

EDIT:
Here is I how am loading the config file:

```
 string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\SoftOne";
            string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath, "*" + DisplayName + "*");

            if (directories.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] configFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directories[0], "*.config");

                if (configFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFiles[0]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Probably you're looking at the wrong config file. How do you search for it?

Comment: Check this SO entry:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589/loading-system-servicemodel-configuration-section-using-configurationmanager

Comment: @AmiramKorach I was also suspicious about that but I double checked the location and it is the file I need.

Comment: Please add the code you're using