# C# WCF web.config

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I have a `web.config` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="InstantMessagingBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="200000" maxArrayLength="200000" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000" authenticationScheme="Ntlm"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    ...
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

I want my service to read the `closeTimeOut` from this file.
I know how to read from the `AppSetting` section but I don't know how to do it here.

Comment: Can you paste the <services> node of your web.config ?

Comment: Try showing you hosting code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question: [Loading System.ServiceModel configuration section using ConfigurationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19589/429541)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session.Timeout to know timeout value.

Look at following link which will help you to understand

[Access settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0.aspx)

or  you can set the Information app setting and Access it