# Configuring endpoints in separate project in WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, castle-windsor

I need to shift container registering endpoints (Windsor) from Global.asax file to new project. I'd like to retrieve a section from Web.config file where endpoints are defined but I don't know how to reach that file and section from separate project. I have tried something like this:

```
 ClientSection clientSection = new MvcApplication().Application.Get((ClientSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client"))
```

but it seems it is wrong path. Any ideas how to copy section from Web.config in one project into configuration file in another?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589/loading-system-servicemodel-configuration-section-using-configurationmanager

Comment: What type of project is this "new project"? Web App? Class Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to get client section:

```
ClientSection clientSection = 
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;
```

Comment: but how to refer to the MVC or frm mvc here. In mvc global.asax I was trying smtg like:  _container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.Named("Proj.Apllication.Ioc")) but I couldnt add this reference due to the circular dependency ?

Comment: not expert in Windsor :) this works fine when I tried in my code asp.NET code