# .NET 6 Winforms application how to add sections to app.config

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 Winform application (C#) with an `app.config` and an `appsettings` section for which I am using `AppSettingsReader` to read the values.

I would like to add the equivalent of `System.ServieModel`, however, as soon as I do, the `AppSettingsReader` crashes with an unknown section.

Does anyone have an example of adding system.service model (WCF bindings) to a .NET 6 application (not a web app)?

Comment: You have to use equivalent tools such as `System.ServiceModel.Primitives`.

Comment: .Net does not support WCF staff anymore, but you have options to consume WCF in .NET6,  instead defining `system.serviceModel` in config you can define your `httpBinding`,`netTcpBinding` as `static` members programmatically.

Comment: NET does not currently support creating WCF services, but you can create WCF clients in .NET to call WCF services.If you want to use system.serviceModel, you need to install [System.ServiceModel.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Http).

Comment: You can check [What's new in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5#windows-communication-foundation) and [Add a WCF service reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2022#to-add-a-reference-to-an-external-service-net-core-projects-including-net-5-and-later).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I created a .Net 4.8 application and implemented my code there by  using the serviceModel in app.config and calling the client generated by svcutil.   However, the same approach in .Net 6. results in an exception ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognised config section ServiceModel.   I've tried to use the ServiceModel.Federation namespace to build the bindings in the app.config manually but have had no luck and don't seem to be able to find an example.

Comment: Sorry forgot: I am creating the client endpoint, bindings and behaviors, not server side.

Comment: Are you also using the `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` and `System.ServiceModel.Http` namespaces? You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440491/17218587).

Comment: Yes, anything with System.ServiceModel in it has been included.  Same exception, Unrecognised section System.Service model.    I would be interested in seeing if anyone has an example of using system.service model in app.config on a net.6 winform app.

Comment: Maybe you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589/loading-system-servicemodel-configuration-section-using-configurationmanager).

Comment: Hi, thanks, I took a look through, however, the issue is that adding ServiceModel to the app.config causes the app to crash when it tries to read the app.config regardless of the approach taken to read the config file.  I am still unable to find a .Net6 (console) application where someone is able to read that section.